# I want to append parameter to url using ruby gsub

Tags: ruby, regex

I have chunk of HTML code containing image tags inside a variable e.g.

```
html_chunk = "<p><img src="https://www.eff.org/files/HTTPS_Everywhere_new_logo.jpgxcvxcvxcv" style="width: 360px; height: 311px; " /><img alt="" src="https://mylocal/media/a649vb?filename=1339756119888_sprites_ie6.png&amp;amp;type=attachment" /></p>"
```

I want to append aditional parameter say `"&foo=123"` to all the `src` attributes of image tags inside that variable.

I tried using Ruby's `gsub!` method

```
html_chunk.gsub!(/"(http[s]?:\/\/.*?\/([media]+).*\")/) {|src| "#{src}&foo=123}"}
```

but it appends the parameter after quotes like this

```
<img alt="" src="https://mylocal/media/a649?filename=1339756119888_sprites_ie6.png&amp;amp;type=attachment"&_foo=123 />
```

Comment: Why is this tagged javascript if you want to use Ruby?

Comment: just use nokogiri and save tons of time.

Comment: Nokogiri makes the parsing very slow..

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the last " outside of the capture group. [^"] means any char that isn't a quote:

```
html_chunk.gsub! %r|"(https?://[^"]*/media/[^"]*)|, '"\\1&foo=123'
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript:

```
// Create a dummy DOM element
var dom = document.createElement( 'div' );
dom.innerHTML = html_chunk;

// Get all the images
var imgs = dom.getElementsByTagName( 'img' );

// Loop through'em
[].forEach.call( imgs, function( img ) {

    // Add a string to their src
    img.src += '&foo=123';
} );
```

I'm pretty sure there is a DOM parser in ruby.